# What is the status of all the Primarchs?

Tags: warhammer-40k, primarchs

I'm not too caught up on the 40K Universe, though I have heard, through the grapevine things like

"The Lion has awoken..."

Being a Dark Angels fan, that certainly caught my attention. So what is the *current* status of all the Primarchs? (including Chaos)

Comment: Isn't this technically more of a scifi stackexchange (story question) rather than a RPG question?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to flag to migrate a question but this definitly belongs in scifi instead of here as it's entirely to do with the story of the 40k universe, not any of the RPGs

Comment: @Psycrow possibly, but the fact that this was asked, and answered 2 years ago, as well as the fact that the tag exists here, would probably argue otherwise. The 40k universe takes place in a lot of rpgs, such as Dark Heresy and Rogue Trader.

Comment: Whoops, I really need to check the dates on questions that pop up on the front page! However I still stand by what I said, a question purely about lore belongs in SciFi, a question specifically about a roleplaying game belongs here.

Comment: Otherwise, flag it for moderator attwntion, if you still feel that way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am unaware of any changes...

Official list of primarchs says that:

1. Lion El'Jonson sleeps at the rock.
2. +++Records expunged+++
3. Fulgrim, Daemon prince, rules over a pleasure world.
4. Perturabo, Daemon prince, ruler of Mendregard
5. Jaghatai Khan's location is unknown. Possibly lost in the webway.
6. Leman Russ disappeared in to the eye of terror, unknown.
7. Rogal Dorn, possibly dead, possibly alive, skeleton hand found.
8. Konrad Curze: Terminated, killed by Callidus assassin.
9. Sanguinius, slain by Arch-Traitor Horus.
10. Ferrus Manus, slained by Fulgrim.
11. +++Records expunged+++
12. Angron, Daemon Prince.
13. Roboute Guilliman, Lord Commander of the Imperium
14. Mortarion, Daemon Prince, rules over a plague planet.
15. Magnus the Red, Daemon Prince, rules over planet of the Sorcerers. **Probably imprisoned in the webway**
16. Horus Lupercal, Arch-Traitor slain by the God-Emperor of Man.
17. Lorgar Aurelian, Daemon Prince, lord of Sicarius.
18. Vulkan, unknown. Possibly alive.
19. Corvus Corax, unknown, left for eye of Terror.
20. Alpharius Omegon, Unknown.

Regarding the lost primarchs: There is absolutely no information about them, they have been wiped from the existence; only their brothers and emperor know their fate. Rumors say that one (and his legion) has been wiped by Leman Russ and his wolves, fate of the other is unknown but apparently his legion has merged with Ultramarines.

Comment: Being that vulkan is a perpetual, odds of him being dead are fairly low...

Comment: I'm mixed about the Records expunged parts... While it's fun and all, if there is info about them somewhere, well, it's part of the answer. If not, maybe it should be specified

Comment: @Cristol.GdM Records expunged is literally all you'll ever find out. There are some books where the remaining primarchs discuss the fate of their "fallen brothers", such as a 2 statues that are completely covered up, but their identity is never revealed. Nobody knows.

Comment: @Theik Ok I see; and actually the last edit is perfect, good job to the author :)

Comment: Additionally, it has been strongly suggested that Vulkan is currently held prisoner by Trazyn the Infinite, a Necron Overlord/Phaeron (he's an Overlord but he has no Phaeron to which he reports). He has gotten into conflict with the Salamanders as a plot to steal the Spear of Vulkan. Which he was given freely. Tip first. Several times.